# What's the difference between Angular Universal and adding @angular/ssr to a Regular Angular App?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

1. **Wha's the main difference between starting a project with Angular Universal and adding the package `@angular/ssr` to an existing Angular application?** I’m trying to understand the pros/cons of each option in terms of design, operation, and maintenance.
2. **Are there any particular situations where one method is better than another?** For example, where the project is already at an advanced stage of development, and needs to add SSR to improve SEO or initial load time.
3. **Are there any special limitations that I have when choosing Angular Universal and `@angular/ssr?`**

Answer (score 2):

I was researching it then I found it in [official repo of Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal)

> Angular Universal was a project to expand on the core APIs from
> Angular (platform-server) to enable developers to do server side
> rendering of Angular applications in a variety of scenarios.
>
> This repository has been merged into the Angular CLI repo In version
> 17, Universal has been moved into the Angular CLI repo. Code has been
> refactored and renamed (mostly under @angular/ssr now), but the core
> functionality and architecture is unchanged.
>
> Universal features such as server-side rendering and build-time
> prerendering are now directly supported in Angular CLI and do not
> require a separate integration with Universal.
>
> As a result, this repository is effectively in maintenance mode and is
> no longer accepting contributions. Improvements to Angular's
> SSR/prerendering tooling should be made against the CLI repo directly.
> Universal versions under long-term support (LTS) are still maintained
> by the Angular team and will continue to receive security fixes until
> they fall out of LTS.